# Iterating over an Object to verify if it's keys exist in an Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, javascript-objects

Heres the situation -

I have an Array and an Object.

say:

```
var Array = ["field1", "field2", "field3"];
var Object = { field1: undefined, field2: undefined, field3: undefined, field4: undefined, field5: undefined}
```

*the values in the object don't really matter right now

Using underscoreJS i want to iterate over the Object and check to see if each of the keys exists in the Array array. If it does i want to be able to set its value to true and if not i want to set it to false.

So far i've tried:

```
 _.mapObject(Object, function(val, key){

        for (var j = 0; j < Array.length; j++) {
            currentKey = Array[j];
            (function(i){
                for (var k = 0; k < Array.length; k++) {
                    if(key === Array[i]) {
                        return val = true;
                    } else {
                        return val = false;
                    }
                }
            })(currentKey);
        }

    });
```

Shit is very confusing; for me at least. Any help is appreciatated.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to name your objects `Object` and your arrays `Array`, as that are the built-in class* names and you're likely to get lots of funny errors later. Instead, how about `obj` and `arr`?

Comment: You must not `return false` if only one of the keys is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using underscore:

```
    var result = _.mapObject(Object, function(value, field){
        return _.contains(Array, field);
    });
```

or if you want to change Object itself:

```
    var result = _.each(Object, function(value, field){
        return _.contains(Array, field);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Gruff bunny!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need underscore for this:

```
var a = ["field1", "field2", "field3"];
var o = { field1: undefined, field2: undefined, field3: undefined, field4: undefined, field5: undefined}

for (var k in o) {
  o[k] = a.indexOf(k) != -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said there's no need for underscore.

You can use the native `Object.keys` to return an array of `own` keys then iterate over them. `Object.keys` will not include inherited properties from the prototype chain which `for in` will. It is however considerably slower which could be a problem with large data-sets.

```
Object.keys(obj)
    .forEach(function (key) {
        obj[key] = (arr.indexOf(key) !== -1);
    });
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9zLr4jho/1/)

[Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `underscore` to do this:

```js
var arr = ['a','b','c'],
        obj = {a: '', b: '', c: '', d:''};

function check (a, o) {
    for (var key in o) {
        if (a.indexOf(key) != -1) {
            o[key] = true
        }
    }
}

check(arr,obj);

document.write(JSON.stringify(obj))
```